# integer, list Maya Python concatenation

Tags: python, maya, curves, nurbs

I have a problem. I am writing a Python-Maya script. I'm trying to extrude a list of objects to another list of objects, but I get the following error when I try to do it(the error is not the line where I start the for loop):

```
 Error: line 1: TypeError: file <maya console> line 45: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

#

```
def extrude_():
    for i in range(listOfCircles):
        mc.select(listOfCurves[0], all=True)
        mc.select(listOfCircles[0], all=True)
        mc.extrude(listOfCurves[0]+str(i), listOfCircles[0]+str(i), et=2)

        return
```

listOfCircles and listOfCurves are global variables, so I don't think I need to pass them to the function..

Comment: The error tells you what you need to know: the `range()` function expects a integer as it's argument rather than a list. What you probably want is `range(len(listOfCircles))`.

Comment: I tried to run the code with range(len(listOfCircles)) even before but it gives me this error : 

 # Error: line 1: TypeError: file <maya console> line 49: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list #

Comment: Inspect the contents of listOfCurves[0] by printing it out in the loop. If it is a list, then you cannot "add" (+) a string with that list.

Comment: just use for i, curve in enumerate(listOfCircles): ?

Comment: @kartikg3
I inspected the list already...the result is:
circle_0
circle_1
circle_2
circle_3
circle_4
...
...
...
circle_252
circle_253
circle_254
curve_0
curve_1
curve_2
curve_3
...
...
...
curve_252
curve_253
curve_254
curve_0
Isn't it strange that in the end I have curve_0?
##############
I tried  for i, curve in enumerate(listOfCircles): 
as you suggested, but nothing changes. The error is always the same

Comment: However, if I tried to change this line 
**mc.extrude(listOfCurves[0]+str(i), listOfCircles[0]+str(i), et=2)** in this one:
**mc.extrude(listOfCurves[i], listOfCircles[i], et=2)**

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understood what you explained you want to achieve your code could be as following:

```
def extrude():
    for i in range(len(listOfCircles)):
        mc.extrude(listOfCurves[i], listOfCircles[i], et=2)
```